# Cassandra sorting is not working

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am having Cassandra table where I want data to be sorted according to `action_time` field.

Please find below script details.

```
    cassandra@cqlsh:activitylog> desc keyspace;cassandra@cqlsh:activitylog> desc keyspace;

    CREATE KEYSPACE activitylog WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '3'}  AND durable_writes = true;

    CREATE TABLE activitylog.activity_log (
        id timeuuid,
        action_time timestamp,
        vendor_id bigint,
        PRIMARY KEY (id, action_time)
    ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (action_time ASC)
        AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
        AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
        AND comment = ''
        AND compaction = {'min_threshold': '4', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32'}
        AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
        AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
        AND default_time_to_live = 0
        AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
        AND max_index_interval = 2048
        AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
        AND min_index_interval = 128
        AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
        AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';

    cassandra@cqlsh:activitylog> select id,action_time,vendor_id from activity_log;

     id                                   | action_time              | vendor_id
    --------------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------
     4ce8ea50-ea55-11e4-a220-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 13:11:18+0530 |      1234
     4ce8ea53-ea55-11e4-a220-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 13:11:18+0530 |      1234
     86aedb31-ea7f-11e4-aa45-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 18:13:34+0530 |      1234
     09ec5340-ea55-11e4-a220-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 13:09:25+0530 |      1234
     65e85a71-ea7f-11e4-aa45-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 18:12:39+0530 |      1234
     65e85a72-ea7f-11e4-aa45-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 18:12:39+0530 |      1234
     86aedb33-ea7f-11e4-aa45-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 18:13:34+0530 |      1234
     4ce8ea52-ea55-11e4-a220-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 13:11:18+0530 |      1234
     86aedb32-ea7f-11e4-aa45-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 18:13:34+0530 |      1234
     09ec5341-ea55-11e4-a220-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 13:09:25+0530 |      1234
     20935240-ea70-11e4-8fd7-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 16:23:20+0530 |      1234
     65e85a73-ea7f-11e4-aa45-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 18:12:39+0530 |      1234
     20935243-ea70-11e4-8fd7-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 16:23:20+0530 |      1234
     86aedb30-ea7f-11e4-aa45-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 18:13:34+0530 |      1234
     09ec5343-ea55-11e4-a220-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 13:09:25+0530 |      1234
     20935241-ea70-11e4-8fd7-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 16:23:20+0530 |      1234
     65e85a70-ea7f-11e4-aa45-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 18:12:39+0530 |      1234
     20935242-ea70-11e4-8fd7-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 16:23:20+0530 |      1234
     09ec5342-ea55-11e4-a220-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 13:09:25+0530 |      1234
     4ce8ea51-ea55-11e4-a220-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 13:11:18+0530 |      1234


    CREATE KEYSPACE activitylog WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '3'}  AND durable_writes = true;

    CREATE TABLE activitylog.activity_log (
        id timeuuid,
        action_time timestamp,
        vendor_id bigint,
        PRIMARY KEY (id, action_time)
    ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (action_time ASC)
        AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
        AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
        AND comment = ''
        AND compaction = {'min_threshold': '4', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32'}
        AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
        AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
        AND default_time_to_live = 0
        AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
        AND max_index_interval = 2048
        AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
        AND min_index_interval = 128
        AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
        AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';

    cassandra@cqlsh:activitylog> select id,action_time,vendor_id from activity_log;

     id                                   | action_time              | vendor_id
    --------------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------
     4ce8ea50-ea55-11e4-a220-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 13:11:18+0530 |      1234
     4ce8ea53-ea55-11e4-a220-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 13:11:18+0530 |      1234
     86aedb31-ea7f-11e4-aa45-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 18:13:34+0530 |      1234
     09ec5340-ea55-11e4-a220-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 13:09:25+0530 |      1234
     65e85a71-ea7f-11e4-aa45-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 18:12:39+0530 |      1234
     65e85a72-ea7f-11e4-aa45-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 18:12:39+0530 |      1234
     86aedb33-ea7f-11e4-aa45-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 18:13:34+0530 |      1234
     4ce8ea52-ea55-11e4-a220-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 13:11:18+0530 |      1234
     86aedb32-ea7f-11e4-aa45-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 18:13:34+0530 |      1234
     09ec5341-ea55-11e4-a220-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 13:09:25+0530 |      1234
     20935240-ea70-11e4-8fd7-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 16:23:20+0530 |      1234
     65e85a73-ea7f-11e4-aa45-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 18:12:39+0530 |      1234
     20935243-ea70-11e4-8fd7-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 16:23:20+0530 |      1234
     86aedb30-ea7f-11e4-aa45-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 18:13:34+0530 |      1234
     09ec5343-ea55-11e4-a220-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 13:09:25+0530 |      1234
     20935241-ea70-11e4-8fd7-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 16:23:20+0530 |      1234
     65e85a70-ea7f-11e4-aa45-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 18:12:39+0530 |      1234
     20935242-ea70-11e4-8fd7-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 16:23:20+0530 |      1234
     09ec5342-ea55-11e4-a220-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 13:09:25+0530 |      1234
     4ce8ea51-ea55-11e4-a220-4943c7dd5536 | 2015-04-24 13:11:18+0530 |      1234
```

As we can see select statement is not sorted as per action_time column. But while getting description of table its showing that data will be sorted by action_time in ASC order.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 3):

It is important to note that Cassandra will enforce a sorting order **only** within a partition key.  In your case, your partition key is `id`, and your table definition indicates that all rows with similar partition keys will be ordered by your clustering key `action_time`.

Your problem is not that sort order does not work.  It is that the cardinality of your partition key is so high that Cassandra doesn't *have* anything to sort.

This becomes clear when you model your data with a lower-cardinality partition key.  Watch what happens when I re-create your table as `activity_log_by_vendor`  with a re-ordered PRIMARY KEY:

```
CREATE TABLE activity_log_by_vendor (
    id timeuuid,
    action_time timestamp,
    vendor_id bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY (vendor_id, action_time, id));

aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> SELECT * FROm activity_log_by_vendor WHERE vendor_id = 1234;

 vendor_id | action_time              | id
-----------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------
      1234 | 2015-04-24 02:39:25-0500 | 09ec5340-ea55-11e4-a220-4943c7dd5536
      1234 | 2015-04-24 02:39:25-0500 | 09ec5341-ea55-11e4-a220-4943c7dd5536
      1234 | 2015-04-24 02:39:25-0500 | 09ec5342-ea55-11e4-a220-4943c7dd5536
      1234 | 2015-04-24 02:39:25-0500 | 09ec5343-ea55-11e4-a220-4943c7dd5536
      1234 | 2015-04-24 02:41:18-0500 | 4ce8ea50-ea55-11e4-a220-4943c7dd5536
      1234 | 2015-04-24 02:41:18-0500 | 4ce8ea51-ea55-11e4-a220-4943c7dd5536
      1234 | 2015-04-24 02:41:18-0500 | 4ce8ea52-ea55-11e4-a220-4943c7dd5536
      1234 | 2015-04-24 02:41:18-0500 | 4ce8ea53-ea55-11e4-a220-4943c7dd5536
      1234 | 2015-04-24 05:53:20-0500 | 20935240-ea70-11e4-8fd7-4943c7dd5536
      1234 | 2015-04-24 05:53:20-0500 | 20935241-ea70-11e4-8fd7-4943c7dd5536
      1234 | 2015-04-24 05:53:20-0500 | 20935242-ea70-11e4-8fd7-4943c7dd5536
      1234 | 2015-04-24 05:53:20-0500 | 20935243-ea70-11e4-8fd7-4943c7dd5536
      1234 | 2015-04-24 07:42:39-0500 | 65e85a70-ea7f-11e4-aa45-4943c7dd5536
      1234 | 2015-04-24 07:42:39-0500 | 65e85a71-ea7f-11e4-aa45-4943c7dd5536
      1234 | 2015-04-24 07:42:39-0500 | 65e85a72-ea7f-11e4-aa45-4943c7dd5536
      1234 | 2015-04-24 07:42:39-0500 | 65e85a73-ea7f-11e4-aa45-4943c7dd5536
      1234 | 2015-04-24 07:43:34-0500 | 86aedb30-ea7f-11e4-aa45-4943c7dd5536
      1234 | 2015-04-24 07:43:34-0500 | 86aedb31-ea7f-11e4-aa45-4943c7dd5536
      1234 | 2015-04-24 07:43:34-0500 | 86aedb32-ea7f-11e4-aa45-4943c7dd5536
      1234 | 2015-04-24 07:43:34-0500 | 86aedb33-ea7f-11e4-aa45-4943c7dd5536

(20 rows)
```

By partitioning on `vendor_id`, Cassandra actually has 20 CQL rows to sort.  And since they have the same `vendor_id`, Cassandra will enforce a sort order on `action_time` and `id`, descending (note, I added `id` to the PRIMARY KEY to ensure uniqueness).

Last month I wrote an article for [PlanetCassandra](http://www.planetcassandra.org) describing this behavior: [We Shall Have Order!](http://planetcassandra.org/blog/we-shall-have-order/)

DataStax's Patrick McFadin also has an article that does a great job discussing how to model these types of problems: [Getting Started With Time Series Data Modeling](http://planetcassandra.org/blog/getting-started-with-time-series-data-modeling/).

Give those two articles a read, and they should help you get a better understanding of how to properly leverage Cassandra clustering order.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detail explanation also I gone through your post related to this. It helped me a lot to understand.